# Dynamic Mutidimensional array value Count using php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, for-loop

I am trying to count the array value in the multidimensional array for the following Array value.

```
$allMultiGridRes = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => grid multi col1
                    [2] => grid multi col2
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => grid multi col1
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => grid multi col1
                    [2] => grid multi col2
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => grid multi col1
                    [2] => grid multi col2
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => grid multi col1
                    [2] => grid multi col2
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => grid multi col1
                    [2] => grid multi col2
                )
        )
)
```

I am expecting the following output.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [grid multi col1] => 3
            [grid multi col2] => 3
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [grid multi col1] => 3
            [grid multi col2] => 2
        )
)
```

I have tried the following method using the `for loop` but I cannot able to achieve the above output like above.

```
$allMultiGridRes =array();
$paramCheck =array();
foreach ($allMultiGridRes as $gMKey => $GMvalue){
    if(!empty($GMvalue)){
        foreach ($GMvalue as $gMKey2 => $gMValue2){
            if(!empty($gMValue2)){
                $allGridCount[$gMKey2] = array_count_values($gMValue2);
                foreach ($gMValue2 as $gMKey3 => $gMValue3){
                    $paramCheck = !empty($allGridCount[$gMKey2])?$allGridCount[$gMKey2]:array();
                    $GMindex1 = $gMValue3;
                    $allGridCount[$gMKey2][$GMindex1] = array_key_exists($GMindex1,$paramCheck) ? $allGridCount[$gMKey2][$GMindex1]++ : 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using this method I am getting the following output but value are not counting as expected.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [grid multi col1] => 1
            [grid multi col2] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [grid multi col1] => 1
            [grid multi col2] => 1
        )
)
```

I am open to suggestions also I have tried a lot of methods but still I cannot achieve it. I am stuck here for long time

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share live demo please, or share data sample in php code

Comment: Not sure how you count them. And why should not [0] be counted? In [1] i count 2 col1 and 2 col1, you say there is three of each?

Comment: @C2486 you mean a var_export?

Comment: php code for `$allMultiGridRes` , it help to run at our side

Comment: @C2486 I have updated the code check it now.

Comment: @Prashanth : Bhai I was talking about this array formed in php that `Alive to Die` given here : https://eval.in/1004977

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_reduce` and `foreach`

```
$allMultiGridRes = ;//Your array

$result = array_reduce($allMultiGridRes, function($c, $v){
    foreach ( $v as $key => $value ) {
        if ( !isset( $c[$key] ) ) $c[$key] = array();

        foreach( $value as $o ) {
            if ( !isset( $c[$key][$o] ) ) $c[$key][$o] = 0;
            $c[$key][$o]++;
        }
    }
    return $c;
},array());

print_r( $result );
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [grid multi col1] => 3
            [grid multi col2] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [grid multi col1] => 3
            [grid multi col2] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: Great Yes it works @eddie but the key index count should start with `[1] ,[2]`.

Comment: @Prashanth Yes, That will follow the key on your array.

Comment: I used 0 and 1 on mine, so that is why you are getting that

Comment: Hi @Eddie How can I get the same kind output for the inputs give on the following link. [Demo](https://eval.in/1005019)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171147/discussion-between-prashanth-and-eddie).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use second `foreach()` iteration `key` to distinguishing records as well as for proper addition

```
$allGridCount = [];
foreach ($allMultigridRes as $gMKey => $GMvalue){
    if(!empty($GMvalue)){
        foreach ($GMvalue as $gMKey2 => $gMValue2){
            if(!empty($gMValue2)){
                foreach ($gMValue2 as $gMKey3 => $gMValue3){
                    $allGridCount[$gMKey2][$gMKey3][$gMValue3] = (isset($allGridCount[$gMKey2][$gMKey3][$gMValue3])) ? $allGridCount[$gMKey2][$gMKey3][$gMValue3]+1 : 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre/>";print_r($allGridCount);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/1004977

***Note:-***  Instead of `!empty()` use `is_array() && count()` to check that it's an array and have some value in it to iterate furhter

```
$allGridCount = [];
foreach ($allMultigridRes as $GMvalue){
    if(is_array($GMvalue) && count($GMvalue) >0){
        foreach ($GMvalue as $gMKey2 => $gMValue2){
            if(is_array($gMValue2) && count($gMValue2) >0){
                foreach ($gMValue2 as $gMKey3 => $gMValue3){
                    $allGridCount[$gMKey2][$gMKey3][$gMValue3] = (isset($allGridCount[$gMKey2][$gMKey3][$gMValue3])) ? $allGridCount[$gMKey2][$gMKey3][$gMValue3]+1 : 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre/>";print_r($allGridCount);
```